# Google Maps API will not display GeoJSON data

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geojson

I'm trying for the first time to extract data from a GeoJSON file and display it in Google Maps. I just want to place a simple Google Maps marker at the coordinates in the geojson. Tried reading what I could on the net on the GM API and geojson but I feel like I'm missing something very simple.

Here is the **main map code**:

```
<script>
var map;
  function initMap()
  {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 16,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.061146,34.799387),
      mapTypeId: 'hybrid'
    });
  }
map.data.loadGeoJson('toilets.geojson');
map.data.setMap(map);
</script>
```

Here is the **toilets.geojson** file:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            34.799339175224304,
            32.061136963943106
          ]
      }
    }]
}
```

Just want a regular marker to appear at those coordinates

Answer (score 1):

One issue is the `map` variable is out of scope when you are loading the GeoJSON.  That code needs to be inside the `initMap` function.

```
<script>
var map;
  function initMap()
  {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 16,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.061146,34.799387),
      mapTypeId: 'hybrid'
    });
    map.data.loadGeoJson('toilets.geojson');
    map.data.setMap(map);
  }
</script>
```

- [proof of concept fiddle (local JSON data](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/w63kvLhs/)
- [proof of concept fiddle (external JSON file)](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/w63kvLhs/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 16,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.061146, 34.799387),
    mapTypeId: 'hybrid'
  });
  map.data.addGeoJson(geoJsonData);
  map.data.setMap(map);
}
var geoJsonData = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {},
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
        34.799339175224304,
        32.061136963943106
      ]
    }
  }]
};
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap"></script>
```